# unable to store utf8mb4 in mysql

Tags: mysql, django, collation

I'm using django with mysql. I want to change my unicode utf8 to utf8mb4 for storing emojis. i did try and  change some fields. here is the variables-

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 
 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci    |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Right now when i'm trying to add an emoji its prints **?** question mark.
I also change my databse and my.cnf file-

```
DATABASES = {
    ’default’: {
        ’ENGINE’: ’django.db.backends.mysql’,
        ’NAME’: ’example’,
        ’USER’: ’example’,
        ’PASSWORD’: ’example’,
        ’HOST’: ’’,
        ’PORT’: ’’,
        ’OPTIONS’: {’charset’: ’utf8mb4’},
    }
}
```

and my.cnf-

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

somehow the collation server is still shows the utf8 encode and collation connection shows utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: As described [with your existing question on the DBA stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291579/storing-emojis-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment570617_291579), your connection variables do not provide the full picture. Your table definition is required to understand the scope of what needs to be done. If your table does not support 4-byte characters, your connection settings are irrelevant.

Comment: @matigo so how to do that? well i'm using django for creating those tables by using modelfields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved. If anyone knows about any emoji picker in django to use in model field let me know.